# Block elements in rows display like inline-block in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

When placing a block-level element (e.g. **h1**, **p**, etc) in a div with class="row" causes it to behave like an inline-block element! If I remove the "row" div it shows correctly. What am I doing wrong?

The example code below results in the heading and paragraph displaying on the same line. I would expect them to display on separate lines.

Example code:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <title>Hello, world!</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are NOT supposed to place any *content* into a `.row` directly.

Instead, put a column (`.col-*`) into a row and then put your content inside the column(s).

Rows and columns in Bootstrap are designed to work as a pair. Never alone.

So, if you just need one column that fills out the entire width of the row, then you put a div with the `col` class inside your row and that's it.

You could also put *content* directly into a `.container` i.e. without using rows and columns. But putting content directly into a row does not serve any purpose and also breaks some things as you have seen.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p>This is a paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply - could've sworn I'd already responded. Yeah, that makes sense. I don't remember having to do that with BS3 though (maybe I just haven't been paying attention!). Thanks for your help.